# Customizing RTSP client library for woza

Tags: ios, live-streaming, wowza, rtsp-client

I have downloaded a library from this [links](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iOS-Video-Encoding.html) its working fine for live streaming with in local network. I am not able to customize this library to communicate with wowza server. Please guide me if anyone knows.

Or else suggest me some other open source ios client library(Encoding foramt should be either H.264 or MPEG 2 or 4) to communicate with wowza server.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install wowza locally on your host, turn it on the max debug level and try to establish the session with you client. Then, in the log, you will see what is going on. As per my experience, wowza standard setup behaves in a pretty expectable way, understands h264 + aac sound. I implemented rtsp client for android, can send you negotiating logs, etc. You, on the other side, could also grab the log on how session is established to check if commands order is ok, all is sane and what the response is.